# keypress event for some characters in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
number:<input type="text" name="number" onkeypress='return numbersonly(event)' />
```

here is my textbox...i have apllied a function o it on keypress..here is the function...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function numbersonly(e){
     var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode
     if (unicode!=8){ //if the key isn't the backspace key (which we should allow)
        if (unicode<48||unicode>57&&unicode!=65) //if not a number
           return false //disable key press
        }
     }
</script>
```

with this keypress function the user can only enter number that is from 0-9 now what i want is that it should acceept only one alphabet that is a whose ascii number is 65...but when i am apllying condition it is not taking a alphabet so can anyone please help me with the condition??

Comment: unicode 65 is A. It seems to work for me http://jsfiddle.net/dqLjp/

Comment: i want it to accept + sign whose ...it is not accepting dat...could u tell me why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+` sign unicode is 43 not 107

Try:

```
function numbersonly(e){
 var unicode=e.charCode? e.charCode : e.keyCode;
 if (unicode!=8){ //if the key isn't the backspace key (which we should allow)
    if ((unicode<48||unicode>57)&&(unicode!=65)&&(unicode!=43)) //if not a number
    return false //disable key press
    }
      }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dqLjp/1/)